# Error:(69, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable i

Tags: android

I was following this tutorial on how to create a RecyclerView on slidenerd and when i run my app is showing me this error (Error:(69, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable i), pointing to this part of my code as error(current.iconId=icons[i];
              current.title=titles[i];)below are my codes

public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private View containerView;
private MichaelAdapter adapter;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreference(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));
    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    adapter = new MichaelAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return layout;

}
  public static List<information> getData() {
      List<information> data = new ArrayList<>();
      int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_podcasts, R.drawable.ic_magazine};
      String[] titles = {"Podcast", "Magazine"};
      for (int i = 0; i< titles.length && i< icons.length; i++) ;
      {
        information current=new information();
          current.iconId=icons[i];
          current.title=titles[i];
          data.add(current);
      }
      return data;
  }


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.draw_open, R.string.draw_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
                mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                saveToPreference(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
  if (!mUserLearnedDrawer&& !mFromSavedInstanceState){
      mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
  }


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}

public static void saveToPreference(Context context,String preferenceName,String preferenceValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName,preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readFromPreference(Context context,String preferenceName,String defaultvalue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName,defaultvalue);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is the comma at the end of `for (int i = 0; i< titles.length && i< icons.length; i++) ;`, which is a for without a *body*. In your case i is defined in the context of the foor-loop and not visible outside of its body, giving you the compile time error `i is not defined`. Remove the `;` after the closing bracket of your for loop

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i< titles.length && i< icons.length; i++) ;
{
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i< titles.length && i< icons.length; i++) {
```